# Postfix is not working but also isn't throwing any errors

Tags: debian, postfix

I followed this guide http://wiki.nefarius.at/linux/der_perfekte_mail-server to setup postfix and dovecot on my debian server. But for some reason the webinterface on example.org/postfixadmin is not showing up. When I do `postfix status` in only gives me

```
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_overquota_bounce=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_limit_message=Sorry, the user's maildir has overdrawn his diskspace quota, please try again later.
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_override=yes
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is running: PID: 23701
```

This doesn't seem like something serious is wrong. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, postfix is running itself, but you have some issues with postfixadmin (that btw can also be installed using the package manager, given you are using debian or ubuntu)

For further diagnosis you should check, whether postfixadmin has been setup correctly:

- were there any errors when you installed it?
- Did you run the setup.php?
- You could also try to reconfigure postfixadmin using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure  postfixadmin` or reinstalling using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall postfixadmin`

However, if that is not an issue, check apache:

- what do apache's logs say?
- try restarting apache
- did you open port 80 and 443 on your firewall?

Let me know if I can help you further. I had a hard start into Linux Administration using Högi's tutorials myself ;)

Comment: It worked! The error was that i accidentally typed an " instead of an ' which kind of crashed everything. It didn't threw any exceptions thats why I had to manually go through all the configuration files until I found the mistake in line 411. Sigh...

Comment: OMG. Glad that you found it! Sometimes it's just one stupid little character that messes up everything... However for the sake of completeness: would you mind to post your findings as a seperate answer and mark it as the solution? That way the question shows up as answered. :)

Comment: I mark it as the solution in 22 hours

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the mistake! It only took me like several hours...

I wrote:

```
$CONF['postfix_admin_url'] = 'https://example.org/postfixadmin";
```

but it should have been:

```
$CONF['postfix_admin_url'] = 'https://example.org/postfixadmin';
```

Only one character in a 450 line file is wrong and nothing worked for apparently no reason...

I went through all of the many config-files until I found the error. I later found out that there were several warnings in the apache logs which mostly didn't really mean anything. One of them could have lead me to this file (but not the line).
Linux-console programs really need to improve on user friendly exception handling

Comment: What does this have to do with user-friendliness? The server programm even gave the correct logs as you stated...

Comment: @dim-0 But it didn't tell me in which line the error was